# How to programmatically get text from TextField

Tags: javafx, textfield, actionevent

I have this code to find all "id" names, but I want to use these names to now get the text from the same fxml.

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {


    Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
    Scene scene = source.getScene();
    ObservableList<Node> stringArray = source.getParent().getChildrenUnmodifiable();
    for (int index = 0; index < stringArray.size(); index++) {
        if (stringArray.get(index).getId() != null) {
            System.out.println(stringArray.get(index).getId());
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: cast `source.getParent()` to `Node` and use `Node.lookup("")` to get `TextField` do cast again to `TextField` and get your text.. remember add `fx:id=` to your `TextField` `Node` No need looping

Comment: _get the text from the same fxml_ doesn't quite make sense to me, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Set `fx:id` to your TextField and call it from code.
In fxml it looks seems:

```
<TextField fx:id="yourTextField"/>
```

So you can declare a TextField variable in java-class using `@FXML` annotation

```
@FXML
TextField yourTextField;

yourTextField.getText();
```